# Tiling 2D textures in random order

Tags: c#, tilemap, platformer, random

I am wondering what the best way to make a random set of 2D textures. Currently I have tried the follow code but I am aware that when this comes to collisions that would be an issue. Therefore I would really appreciate a different method of achieving this.

```
Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            GenPos = new Vector2((800 + (Length * Stone.Width)), (500 - (i * Stone.Height)));


            int number = random.Next(1, 3);

            if (i == 9)
            {
                if (Length < 31)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    Length++;
                }

            }
            else if (number == 1)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Stone, GenPos, Color.White);
            }
            else if (number > 1)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Grass, GenPos, Color.White);
            }

        }
```

This code works except for two critical things, the collision detection method dose not work as the GenPos changes throughout the code and that the Stone and Grass flashes. Also note that the grass is just a place holder for a future texture of Iron_Ore. I am wondering what the best method for achieving this would be because I need it to be able to detect collisions using a similar detection method to:

```
public Boolean StonePlayerCollision()
    {
        if (playerPosition.Y >= (StonePosition.Y + Stone.Height) && playerPosition.Y <= StonePosition.Y ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

If you are to suggest a new method, which would be much better than maintaining this messy system please note that the Tiled area will need to be in the view matrix method as seen below:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null, null, camera.ViewMatrix);
```

I hope that someone will be able to suggest the best / most efficient way of making a randomly tiled textures that can be detected by collisions. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion : Create a Class for your Tile, you could have a seperate class for each type of tile (stone/tree/grass) or you could pass in a case to the Tile class that is handled from within the Tile Class which would determine its Tile Type.  Regardless of what you do, you need to set up a Bounds property for each one of your tiles.  The Bounds Property is just the rectangle at which you are drawing your Tile at.

```
//TheTileClass

public int TileType;
public int TileRow;
public int TileColumn;
public int TileHeight;
public int TileWidth;
public Texture2D theTile;
public Rectangle Bounds;

public Class Tile {
    public void New(int tileType, int Row, int Column, int tileWidth, int tileHeight){
    TileType = tileType;
    TileRow = Row;
    TileColumn = Column;
    TileHeight = tileHeight;
    TileWidth = tileWidth;
    Bounds = new Rectangle((int)(Column * tileWidth), (int)(Row * tileHeight), tileWidth, tileHeight);
}

public void Draw{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(Column * TileWidth, Row * TileHeight, TileWidth, TileHeight);

    switch(TileType){

    //Stone
    case 1:
        theTile = GlobalVariables.StoneImage;
        break;
    //Tree
    case 2:
        theTile = GlobalVariables.TreeImage;
        break;
}

    spriteBatch.Draw(theTile, destinationRectangle, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
}

}

//In your Game Class

//Instanciate TileSet Object at the top of your code where you set all your variables

public List<Tile> tileSet;
public int nbrOfColumns;
public int nbrOfRows;
public int TileHeight 160;
public int TileWidht = 160;
public Random rng = new Random();

//In LoadContent
GlobalVariables.treeImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("treeImg");
GlobalVariables.stoneImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("stoneImg");

//In your Update of your Game Class

if (tileSet.count == 0){

for (intlc = 0; intlc < nbrOfRows; intlc++){
    for (intlc1 = 0; intlc < nbrOfColumns; intlc1++){
        Tile theTile = new Tile(rng.next(1,10), intlc, intlc1, TileWidth, TileHeight);
        tileSet.Add(theTile);
    }
}
}

Public static class GlobalVariables{
    public static Texture2D treeImage;
    public static Texture2D stoneImage;
}

//In your game's Draw Class
foreach(Tile theTile in tileSet){
    theTile.Draw();
}

//For Collision you need to check agaisnt two rectangles
//The character sprites rectangle, and the stone's rectangle

public Rectangle Bounds;
public class Hero{

public void New{
//set the bounds here like in the tile class
}

public void Update{
//update the bounds here
}
}
```

//Back in your game class' Update

use the logic from this link to check for collision, and the prevent movement if
the characters projected position will intersect with the tile that has a type of Stone or tree : [How to detect collision between two directed object?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84208/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-directed-object/84272#84272)

```
foreach (Tile theTile in tileSet){
  if (theTile.TileType == 1 || theTile.TileType == 2){
      if (Hero.Bounds.Intersects(thetile.Bounds){
       //set some boolean that will indicate that the character is moving to an invalid location
       blnCantMove = true;
       break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for only commenting now, Thanks for the help, is the tileSet a new class that I would load all the different kinds of tiles in?

Comment: I would have a tileset class with a list of class tile in it.  That way you can put the work into one tile class, making it as reusable as possible, then expose whichever tile you wish to by indexing the list of them in the class that contains the list of tiles.